# embedding c++ native dll in set up

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I want to embed c++ native dll in set up file created with install shield limited edition.

Hint :- My application created by using c# and c++ native dll.

Here is my example :-

My c++ dll_code

```
extern "c" __declspec(dllexport) int function_c ()
{
    int a=10;
    return a;
}
```

My .net code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport(@"C:\Users\bajwa\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\c++dll\c++_dll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern int function_c();

    void csharp_function()
    {
        int result= function_c(); // calling c++ native  function
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        csharp_function(); // calling c# function.
    }
}
```

When I installed this setup on my computer it runs perfectly.  Because C++ native dll is placed on my computer at "C:\Users\bajwa\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\c++dll\c++_dll.dll".

But when I delete the c++ native dll from that location then it shows the  error.

> dll not fount at this location

Please help and solve my problem.

Comment: You might want to edit your post and use code tags for all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will just need to use a relative path for the imported DLL.  The easiest thing to do would be to copy the DLL to a known folder relative to the executable (maybe even the same folder) and then use that path.  So if they share a folder, your code can become this:

```
 [DllImport("c++_dll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int function_c();
```

Then just modify the installer to place the dll in the correct location.  To test, just change your code and move the dll over, but it should work.